# Apply alias for loop in grape entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api, grape-entity

I would like to get the following JSON.

```
[{"Product":{"CountryName":4848, }},{"Product":{"CountryName":700}]


module API
  module Entities
    class Example < Grape::Entity
      expose(:product) do
        expose(:country_name) do |product, options|
          product.country.name
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The parameters are product and name. I would like to return Product, ProductName.

How to apply alias for looping elements in grape entity framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Product` attribute : use a `'Product'` string instead of the `:product` symbol,
- `CountryName` attribute : you need to create a method in your entity that will return `product.country.name` and expose it in your entity. And then, use an alias so that the key will be `CountryName` as expected (you can see [grape-entity documentation about aliases if need be](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-entity#aliases)).

In your case, this would give :

```
module API
  module Entities
    class Product < Grape::Entity
      expose 'Product' do
        # You expose the result of the country_name method, 
        # and use an alias to customise the attribute name
        expose :country_name, as: 'CountryName'
      end

      private

      # Method names are generally snake_case in ruby, so it feels
      # more natural to use a snake_case method name and alias it
      def country_name
        object.country.name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And in your endpoint, you specify the entity that must be used to serialize the Products instances. In my example, you may have noticed that I took the liberty of renaming the entity to `Product`, which would give us in the endpoint:

```
# /products endpoint
resources :products do
  get '/' do
    present Product.all, with: API::Entities::Product
  end
end
```

Which should get you this kind of output, as expected:

```
[
    { "Product": { "CountryName": "test 1" } },
    { "Product": { "CountryName": "test 2" } }
]
```

Comment: Can you please see my updated question? I have seen alias already. But looping has alias problem. Sorry for the edit

Comment: @Sam: I've updated my answer. I let you check if that correctly answer your problem, I believe it does (I've used this quite a few times myself)